# Turning a servomotor while taking a video using opencv3.1.0 python 3.4.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

i am trying to move my servomotor to 90 degree position, 0 degrees position and 180 degrees position while capturing a video. the code works but the only thing is that the servomotor doesnt move to those position specified as the servomotors just glitches (struggle to turn but doesnt) when i put the servomotor code together with the video code which I have done below. but if i run the code for the servomotors separately it moves to those positions(90 degree position, 0 degrees position and 180 degrees position ) please what am i doing wrong here i cant seem to figure out what am doing wrong in the code. I also want to stream to a webpage instead of saving the video and I used this [method](http://videos.cctvcamerapros.com/raspberry-pi/how-to-setup-video-streaming-server.html) to set up the webpage so I wondering if someone could help me it will be helpfully if someone could help me correct this thanks in advance

**CODE**

```
import time 
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from glob import iglob
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)
pwm=GPIO.PWM(15,50)
pwm.start(5)


camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc =cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out= cv2.VideoWriter('/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/samples/python/dataset/output1.avi', fourcc,20,(640,480))
while True:

     ret,img=camera.read()
     if ret ==True:
        img=cv2.flip(img,1)
        out.write(img)

     cv2.imshow('Video Recording',img)

     cv2.waitKey(1)
camera.release()
out.release()
cv2.destoryAllwindows()



pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(7) #Turn towards 90 degrees 
time.sleep(5) #sleep 2.5 second 
pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(10) #Turn towards 90 degrees 
time.sleep(5) #sleep 2.5 second
pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(5) #Turn towards 90 degrees 
time.sleep(5) #sleep 2.5 second
```

Comment: (W/o even looking at your code) It's possible (I don't know) that this is not actually a software problem but an electrical or power problem. I've experienced much the same if I didn't have my circuit set up the right way or if I didn't have a good enough power supply. The thing that really makes me think this is what you said: "if I run the code for the servomotors separately they move to 90 degrees" and "the servomotor just glitches (struggles to turn)." If it's a hardware/power problem, you're better off getting help from electronics.stackexchange

Comment: @mgarey I meant if I turn the servo motor code separately it goes to the position(90 degree position, 0 degrees position and 180 degrees) but if I put the servomotor code together  with the video stream code which I have done above the servomotor seem to glitches (struggles to turn) but it doesn't turn

Comment: Yes, I understood what you meant. My first comment still stands. However, I do see you have a ```while True``` loop above your move servo code, so how would your program ever get to the place it is supposed to move the servo?